# Mostrar dados de multiplas models na view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Tenho o seguinte problema: Em uma view vou mostrar dados de 8 tabelas diferentes e tenho o seguinte código que montei para levar os dados para a view.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var avisos = (from av in neEAD.mot_avisos
                      join tm in neEAD.mot_turma on av.av_tm_id equals tm.tm_id
                      join ta in neEAD.mot_turmaaluno on tm.tm_id equals ta.ta_tm_id
                      join al in neEAD.mot_aluno on ta.ta_al_id equals al.al_id
                      join tmp in neEAD.mot_turmaprofessor on tm.tm_id equals tmp.tp_tm_id
                      join pf in neEAD.mot_professor on tmp.tp_pf_id equals pf.pf_id
                      join pfd in neEAD.mot_professor_disciplina on pf.pf_id equals pfd.pfd_pf_id
                      join dp in neEAD.mot_disciplina on pfd.pfd_dp_id equals dp.dp_id
                      where (dp.dp_id == 1 && tm.tm_id == 4 && al.al_id == 22)
                      orderby av.av_datacadastro descending
                        select av).ToList();
        return View(avisos);
    }
```

Então tenho um inner join para trazer os dados, mas no final na parte do select eu so consigo selecionar a primeira tabela, e quando coloco assim:

```
    select new {
          av.av_datacadastro,
          av.av_mensagem,
          av.av_titulo,
          pf.pf_nome
   }
```

Meu código da erro na view. Tem como eu colocar mais de um model na view? Como faço com este inner join?

Comment: Use uma `ViewModel`

Comment: Explique melhor, pois eu direciono a minha view na criação para um model especifico, mas como eu faço pra especificar mais de 1 model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira rápida de resolver (porém lenta na execução e frágil) é definindo a *View* da seguinte forma:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

Só que desta forma não há verificação de tipos em tempo de design, e a abordagem dinâmica é sempre mais lenta que a referência estática.

Usando um *ViewModel*, ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var avisos = (from av in neEAD.mot_avisos
                  join tm in neEAD.mot_turma on av.av_tm_id equals tm.tm_id
                  join ta in neEAD.mot_turmaaluno on tm.tm_id equals ta.ta_tm_id
                  join al in neEAD.mot_aluno on ta.ta_al_id equals al.al_id
                  join tmp in neEAD.mot_turmaprofessor on tm.tm_id equals tmp.tp_tm_id
                  join pf in neEAD.mot_professor on tmp.tp_pf_id equals pf.pf_id
                  join pfd in neEAD.mot_professor_disciplina on pf.pf_id equals pfd.pfd_pf_id
                  join dp in neEAD.mot_disciplina on pfd.pfd_dp_id equals dp.dp_id
                  where (dp.dp_id == 1 && tm.tm_id == 4 && al.al_id == 22)
                  orderby av.av_datacadastro descending
                  select new MeuViewModel {
                      DataCadastro = av.av_datacadastro,
                      Mensagem = av.av_mensagem,
                      Titulo, av.av_titulo,
                      Nome = pf.pf_nome
                  }).ToList();

    return View(avisos);
}
```

O *ViewModel* é uma classe que pode ser definida assim:

```
public class MeuViewModel
{
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public String Mensagem { get; set; }
    public String Titulo { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
```

E a *View*:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuViewModel>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou bastante.